# Append multiple digits to the end of eatch lines

Tags: sed, perl

i need to `cat` temperature values in `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon[0-9]/temp[0-9]_input` and append them to the corresponds names in given file.

help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Paste** is made exactly for that (*merge lines of files*).

```
paste --delimiter=':' FULL/PATH/TO/FILE <(cat /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon[0-9]/temp[0-9]_input)
```

Change `FULL/PATH/TO/FILE` with the full path of the file containing the names.

You can change the delimiter if you want to something else like space for example and pipe the output to `column` for better formatting like so:

```
paste --delimiter=' ' FULL/PATH/TO/FILE <(cat /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon[0-9]/temp[0-9]_input) | column -t
```

See [man paste](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/paste.1.html) for extra information.

Comment: Thank you @Raffa ! this is exactly what im looking for. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a shell loop:

```
for f in /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon[0-9]/temp[0-9]_input ; do echo "$f" "$(< $f)"; done
```

Or, use `grep -H` to output the filename:

```
grep -H . /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon[0-9]/temp[0-9]_input
```